# in-app purchase number on windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase

I have application with many in-app purchase. But in windows dev service the max number of in-app purchase is 200. How to add more than 200 in-app purchase?

Answer (score 0):

There is MSDN article how to add more than 200 IAP to your app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn532256%28v=win.10%29.aspx

The solution is to create just a handful of product entries for specific price tiers, with each one able to represent hundreds of products within a catalog.

Comment: But in this way, the transaction of in-app purchase's product can not be trace. I want the transaction can be trace